# TS Remote App and TS Web Access Authentication

Tags: windows-terminal-services, remoteapp

We're looking at replacing a Citrix system with an rdp based one. The idea is we want to give the users a list of applications they can run from a web front end.

I have got most of it working, there's just a couple of bits i'm struggling with or unsure about

1. Whenever i go to the TS Web site i keep getting a certificate invalid issue. How can I get around this? All the traffic is going to be on the internal lan, do i need to run a local cert authority or can i just turn off https connections?
2. After the cert error i hit a forms login page. I dont want the user to have to type in their username and password at any point, i just want all the authentication to be pass through. Once i've logged in at this point i can see my apps, but whenever i launch them i again get asked for credentials? Any idea how to pass these forward as well?

I'm running the servers on Windows 2008 R2 64bit, the clients will be a mix of Windows 7 and Windows XP.

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RD RemoteApp web site is something soldered with a hot iron to suit the need for a quick&dirty web portal for the most basic use. If you need customization, you would need to [create a Sharepoint site embedding a TSPortalWebPart](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee344839%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Of course, you may choose to run this site without SSL, if you like.

Sharepoint sites also support pass-through authentication. Just make sure the site's URI is listed in the "Local intranet" zone within your users' Internet Explorer zone settings to get the credentials passed on automatically upon access.

Comment: Thanks did'nt realise you could plug it into sharepoint. One other thing is i take it you can tell it to use a TS Farm for the apps and not just one server?

Comment: @beakersoft I never tried it, but I suppose you could simply set the RD/TS Connection broker address instead of a single terminal server's address into the webpart properties.